# Cleaning up topics

Tags: hazelcast

We have an application which creates lots of topics.
When there are no more clients listening (cluster-wide) to a specific topic, that topic should be destroyed. But how to find out, in a clustered environment, that there are no more clients listening to that topic? We don't want to destroy the topic if there are other clients listening on that topic on other nodes in the cluster.

Regards
Fredrik

Answer (score 0):

You most probably have to register / unregister them using a distributed MultiMap where the key is the name of the topic and the values are the listeners.

Comment: Is it possible to use `com.hazelcast.spi.EventService.getRegistrations(String serviceName, String topic);`to find out if there are listeners left (cluster-wide) for the specific topic?

Comment: It most probably is possible but you need access to the EventService which is neither recommended nor supported

Comment: If I have a ref. to the topic would it be safe to do `((AbstractDistributedObject) topic).getNodeEngine().getEventService().getRegistrations(TopicService.SERVICE_NAME, this.topic);`

Comment: No it is possible and safe but still not supported to do that. The API might change in the future.

Comment: Would it be a good solution to add a `DistributedObjectListener` and if there are no clients left on one node, destroy the topic and then recreate the topic on the other node when `distributedObjectDestroyed`is invoked if there still are clients listening on other nodes?

Comment: Not sure I got the idea, what does the DOL have to do with clients being connected? And what do you mean by "not connected to one node"?